# Maven assembly set username for tar

Tags: java, maven, build, m2eclipse, sonarqube

I'm using Maven with the Assembly plugin and would like to set the user and group for a tar-file.

I can set access rights to every directory, but without setting the user this is quite useless.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tar is created with the permission of the user running it.  If you want this to be a particular user/group you can run `maven` as that user/group.

Maven may not allow you to use tar as a different user, but if you can do it in ant you can use http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/ to do anything ant can do.

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/usage.html

Comment: Thanks, that is good to know. How do I run Maven with m2e plugin under windows with some user that doesn'T exist on the system? :-) In ANT you can just say: user="Whatever"

Comment: I suspect you need to run ant from maven to do this.

Comment: This seems like missing functionality in the maven assembly plugin.  The desire isn't to run the tar command as a certain user but rather to assign the user and group that own the files within the tar.  Yes you can do this with antrun, but you shouldn't have to.